# Bootstrap accordion not working with Knockout generated items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, accordion

I'm using Knockout to dynamically general a Twitter-Bootstrap accordion. The data-binding appears to be working well and the initial rendering of the accordion works. However, the hyperlinks to toggle the groups open or closed is not working. I *think* I've set the necessary attributes...

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion-testitem-list">
    <!-- ko foreach : { data: items, as: 'testitem' } -->
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-testitem-list" data-bind="text: testitem.Name, attr: { href : '#collapsible' + testitem.ID, 'data-target': '#collapsible' + testitem.ID }">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="attr: { id: '#collapsible' + testitem.ID }" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner"> <span data-bind="text: testitem.Description"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Here's an example of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewransom/3h3qp/

Side question: As I'm new to jsFiddle, can anyone point me to a template (or instructions) that have a jsFiddle set up with the *latest* versions jQuery/Bootstrap/Knockout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should remove the `#` from this line:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { id: '#collapsible' + testitem.ID }" class="accordion-body collapse">
```

Your ids are being generated as "#collapsibleX" when they should just be "collabsibleX"

Comment: A 'Doh!' moment. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes. At least I had the basics right. :)